# Phase flow and potential energy

Tags: classical-mechanics, potential-energy, flow, phase-space, complex-systems

I have a question that our teacher gave us and this is my very first time I see concepts like phase flows. Prove that a positive potential energy always guarantees a phase flow. I should use conservation of energy to prove global existence but I don't know.

Comment: Potential energy being positive doesn't tell us anything as adding a constant to the potential energy and making positive won't change the eom.

Comment: Perhaps the argument is something as follows? If the potential energy if bounded below, the solutions to the eom cannot run off to infinity in finite time. If you are solving the eom on a space without holes (it is complete as a metric space), this should mean you can guarantee existence of a solution to the eom for some minimum time, irrespective of initial conditions.